# unable to assign data from response data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I have a function that should return an array of objects when called. The function looks like this

```
loadTodo(): Todo[]{
var data 
this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}todos`).toPromise().then(res => {
  data = res.json()
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  return data}
```

This results in unexpected behavior where `data` variable gets assigned correctly inside the success response block but is `undefined` when accessed outside the response block.

The function is assigned to a variable with type `Todo[]` and is invoked immediately when the variable is declared. I am quite new to TypeScript and Angular but not to JavaScript. Am I missing something with scope/closure of the function or is this issue related to TypeScript/Angular?

Whole class looks like this:

```
export class TodoDataService {
  API_URL: String = 'http://localhost:3000/'  
  todos: Todo[] = this.loadTodo();
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  loadTodo(): Todo[]{
    this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}todos`).toPromise().then(res => {
      this.parcedTodos = res.json()
      console.log('inside function')
      console.log(this.parcedTodos)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      console.log('outside function')
      console.log(this.parcedTodos)
      return this.parcedTodos
  }
}
```

Comment: How you are calling loadTodo method?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `res.json()` not is neccesary because angular pipes already doing this works. Do you try to assign to variable res directly?

As others friends says, you are doing bad some things.

First: you must read about asynchronous methods

Second: use Observables importing rxjs/Observable; and follow its callbacks flow

Example

```
    export class TodoDataService {
  API_URL: String = 'http://localhost:3000/'  
  todos: Todo[] = this.loadTodo();
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  loadTodo() : Observable<Todo[]>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}todos`);
  }
}
```

And other class consummes this method

```
 todoDataService.loadTodo().subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log("Future response", response);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`http.get()` is asynchronous, which means that when you try to print `parcedTodos` outside the `then` callback, it will still be undefined.

[Asynchronous programming in JS](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `http` calls are `asynchronous`.

You need to make sure you are accessing data only after call is completed.

```
export class TodoDataService {
  API_URL: String = 'http://localhost:3000/'  
  todos: Todo[] = this.loadTodo();
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  loadTodo(): Todo[]{
    this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}todos`).toPromise().then(res => {
      this.parcedTodos = res.json()
      console.log('inside function')
      console.log(this.parcedTodos)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      {
        console.log(this.parcedTodos);
        // This is where your call gets completed. Here you can access assigned data or call another function where you can access data.
      })
      console.log('outside function')
      console.log(this.parcedTodos) // This is called before asynchronous call is completed. Thats why it is undefined yet.
      return this.parcedTodos
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`this.http.get(whatever)` is an `async` call.
Your `data` is `undefined` because you're accessing it before it is actually initialized. i.e. you're initializing it inside the `success` handler (the first argument to `then`), and probably are accessing it before initialization.

All you need to do is make sure you're doing so after the `success` or `error` handler. use `Observable`